# How to align footer text left and right of MSO Word document using html & css?

Tags: html, css, ms-word, xhtml, ms-office

Been stuck on this issue for a long time. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

So I'm supposed to generate reports (Word docs) whose format draws from an xhtml template. Currently, I am trying to format the footer to have the name of the report on the left side and page numbers on the right AND on the same line. I can get the text on opposite sides, but I am having trouble getting the two pieces of text on the same line. Maybe it's the way Word renders html? I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's the default code that was given to me:

```
<div style='mso-element:footer' id='f1'>
<div style='mso-element:para-border-div;border:none;border-top:solid #005686 1.0pt;
mso-border-top-alt:solid #005686 .5pt;padding:1.0pt 0in 0in 0in; width:100%'>
<p class=MsoNormal align=right style='text-align:left;border:none;mso-border-top-alt:
solid #005686 .5pt;padding:0in;mso-padding-alt:1.0pt 0in 0in 0in'>
<span style='color:#005686'>
<!--REPORT-TITLE-->
</span>
<span style='float:right;color:#005686'>Page</span> 
<!--[if supportFields]><span style='color:#005686'><span
style='mso-element:field-begin'></span>PAGE \* MERGEFORMAT<span
style='mso-element:field-separator'></span></span><![endif]--> 
<span style='color:#005686;mso-no-proof:yes'>1</span>
<span style='color:#005686'> </span>
<!--[if supportFields]><span
style='color:#005686;mso-no-proof:yes'><span style='mso-element:field-end'></span></span><![endif]-->
<span style='font-size:10.0pt;color:#005686'>
<o:p></o:p>
</span>
</p>

</div>

<p class=MsoNormal>
<o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Floats not working with office just place table code like this.

```
 <div style='mso-element:footer' id='f1'>  <table style="width: 100%;" class="noborder">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%;text-align: left;">
                <div style='mso-element:para-border-div;border:none;border-top:solid #005686 1.0pt;
            mso-border-top-alt:solid #005686 .5pt;padding:1.0pt 0in 0in 0in; width:100%'>
                    <p class=MsoNormal align=right style='text-align:left;border:none;mso-border-top-alt:
            solid #005686 .5pt;padding:0in;mso-padding-alt:1.0pt 0in 0in 0in'>
                        <span style='color:#005686'>
                            <!--REPORT-TITLE-->
                        </span>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 50%; text-align: right;">
                <span style='color:#005686'>Page</span>
                <!--[if supportFields]><span style='color:#005686'><span
                style='mso-element:field-begin'></span>PAGE \* MERGEFORMAT<span
                style='mso-element:field-separator'></span></span><![endif]-->
                <span style='color:#005686;mso-no-proof:yes'>1</span>
                <span style='color:#005686'> </span>
                <!--[if supportFields]><span
                style='color:#005686;mso-no-proof:yes'><span style='mso-element:field-end'></span></span><![endif]-->
                <span style='font-size:10.0pt;color:#005686'>
                    <o:p></o:p>
                </span>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table></div>



<style>
 //noborder css       
  .noborder,
    .noborder tr,
    .noborder th,
    .noborder td {
        font: 11pt "Calibri";
        border: none;
    }</style>
```